# MySQL - Check if array values with the same id exist

Tags: mysql

I've got table with two fields: id, numbers

I want to check if the same array values (etc 1,2,5,6) already exist in table, but they have to have the same 1nd row number (id).

I've tried with this sql query, but this one doesn't check if there is the same id:

```
SELECT id, numbers FROM `table` WHERE numbers IN (1,2,5,6) AND id = id
```

I know that "id = id" doesn't work, but I posted it so you'll know what I mean.

Comment: You want to know if an ID has all 4 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) num_count, GROUP_CONCAT(numbers ORDER BY numbers) all_numbers
FROM `table`
WHERE numbers IN (1, 2, 5, 6)
GROUP BY id
```

If you only want to see the ones that have all 4 numbers, add:

```
HAVING num_count = 4
```

If you want the IDs that have all and only those 4 numbers, use:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) all_count, SUM(numbers IN (1, 2, 5, 6)) in_count
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id
HAVING all_count = in_count
```

Comment: From I can see, this will do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: On more thing... do you thing it's wise to use this sql query if I presume that this table will have >100.000 rows?

Comment: If you have a composite index on `(id, numbers)` I think it should be OK. Use `EXPLAIN` to see if it will use the index.

Comment: Thank you. But I've just found that this query has a small flaw. If I use:

SELECT id, COUNT() num_count, GROUP_CONCAT(numbers ORDER BY numbers) all_numbers
FROM `table`
WHERE numbers IN (1, 2, 5)
GROUP BY id
HAVING num_count = 3;

I'll get the same id's as with query:

SELECT id, COUNT() num_count, GROUP_CONCAT(numbers ORDER BY numbers) all_numbers
FROM `table`
WHERE numbers IN (1, 2, 5, 6)
GROUP BY id
HAVING num_count = 4;

Comment: Of course. The query doesn't say that they ONLY have the numbers that are listed, just that they have ALL those numbers.